# Error: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory: \'python\'')

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

necesito vuestra ayuda estoy intentando instalar el plugin de Python en Sublime text y me salta el siguiente error:

[image: puglin SublimeREPL]

[image: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python']

El error en concreto es:

"Error: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory: 'python'')"
"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'"

Lo estoy intentando desde un MAC.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola!, podrías proporcionar mas información, la versión de Mac OS que estas utilizando, la versión de Python... y si no tienes instalado Python es probable que sea eso o bien el alias en tu terminal, en Mac de forma nativa el comando para correr scripts de Python no es 'python' si no que 'python3' puedes comprobarlo ejecutando el comando en tu terminal, quedo a la espera y con gusto le ayudamos